# Swift: Retrieving object values from Parse.com based on another attribute

Tags: swift, parse-platform

So what I'm trying to do is retrieve information from a Parse.com database based on an attribute other than objectID. More specifically, I'd like to retrieve an object without using the objectID so I can read its ADDRESS column. The logic so far:

- Write a query that returns the row where the restaurant name is the        same as 'resto'.
- (this is where i'm stuck) retrieve the restaurant's address from the PFQuery and assign that String value to the addressLabel.text variable. 
  Here is the code I have:

  ```
  class FinalView: UIViewController{



      var resto = 'Eddies Cafe'
      var address:String!
      //var phone:String!

     @IBOutlet var restoLabel: UILabel! 

     @IBOutlet var addressLabel: UILabel!

     @IBOutlet var phoneLabel: UILabel!


     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         //the below query returns only one row
         var query = PFQuery(className: "Restaurants")
         query.whereKey("NAME", equalTo: resto)


         var obj = PFObject.getObjectWithID("i dont want this")

         address = obj["ADDRESS"] as? String
         restoLabel.text = resto
         addressLabel.text = address

    }

  }
  ```

I've been reading plenty on how to do it, but all i'm seeing is how to retrieve a PFObject from a query by it's objectID. I know the objectId's myself since it's my parse.com instance, but I need the app to be able to retrieve the data values from the backend based on restaurant name. Is there a way around this? Am I going about it all wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"Restaurant")
    query.whereKey("adress", equalTo:"Eddies Cafe")
    query.limit = 1
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (restaurants: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if let objects = restaurants as? [PFObject] {
                var firstObject = objects[0]
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                    self.restoLabel.text = firstObject["restaurant"] as? String
                    self.adressLabel.text = firstObject["adress"] as? String
                    self.phoneLabel.text =  firstObject["phone"] as? String
                })

            }
        }
    }
```

I used dispatch_async to process view updates in the main queue so you can see your result immediately.